# create div on top of image and then again remove on click of image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here on image click I am creating dynamically div on top of an image .div is created but it is behind the image how to bring it in front i have used z-index property , no on same click event i want to remove the div .. but div is on top of image so img click event not working
How can i do that?

```
var imgLeftPos = $(obj).position().left;
var imgTopPos = $(obj).position().top;

$(obj).wrap('<div class="f1_card"></div>');
$(obj).wrap('<div class="front face"></div>');
$(".f1_card").wrap('<div class="f1_container"></div>');
var div = $("<div class='back face'></div>");
$('.face').after(div);
$('.back').css("left",imgLeftPos+"px");
$('.back').css("top",imgTopPos+"px");
var arrId = parseInt(obj.id.substr(2));
console.log("arrId   = "+arrId)
window.setTimeout(function () {

    $(".back").html(imgArr[arrId]);
},100);
```

Comment: example html and css code would be good, preferably in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use this css property for the dive, but make sure that you contain the div and the image in a container that has *relative position*

```
#div{
    display: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the div is covering the image then the click event on the image will never happen. You will have to register your click event on the new div itself. This is a security issue as much as anything else as it prevents clickjacking.